# Positioning of elements HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my first ever webpage:

https://karmah24.github.io/Coursera/mod2_sol/

In each of the sections the titles pizza, burger, beverages should be on the top right of the section. I've assigned each column: relative position, and the headers: absolute position. But this takes them out of normal document flow and when I view the page with different widths, the lorem epsum content moves up for different sizes.

How can I correct this? And why does the content in the paragraph tag move up for all the sizes since the header is taken out of the document flow?

Also how can I center the entire figure(image + caption)?

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: azure;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
}
.title1, .title2, .title3 {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    border-left: 4px solid black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
.title1 {
    background-color: rgb(223, 209, 25);
}
.title2 {
    background-color: rgb(132, 214, 24);
}
.title3 {
    background-color: aqua;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col_lg_4 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 31.33%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        border: 4px solid black;
        background-color: #909090;
    } 
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 994px) {
    .col_md_6 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 48%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        border: 4px solid black;
        background-color: #909090;
    }
    .col_md_12 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 98%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        border: 4px solid black;
        background-color: #909090;
    } 
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col_sm_12 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 98%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        border: 4px solid black;
        background-color: #909090;
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MENU</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mod2_sol/css/sytles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_6 col_sm_12">
            <header class="title1">PIZZAS</header>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
                <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
            </p>
            <figure>
                <img src="pizza.jpg" alt="pizza" width="50%" height="50%">
                <figcaption>Try our latest Supreme Pizza</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
        <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_6 col_sm_12">
            <header class="title2">BURGERS</header>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
                <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
            </p>
            <figure>
                <img src="burger.jpg" alt="burger" width="50%" height="50%">
                <figcaption>Try our latest Supreme Burger</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
        <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_12 col_sm_12">
            <header class="title3">BEVERAGES</header>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
                <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
            </p>
            <figure>
                <img src="beverages.jpg" alt="beverages" width="50%" height="50%">
                <figcaption>Try our Latest Chillers</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `float: right` instead of `position: absolute;` so the text inside of the paragraph will float around your header.
2. Setup `margin` and `padding` to your paragraph. The browser default is different from browser to browser.
3. Don't use `width="50%" height="50%"` in `img`, they are outdated. Set it in CSS.
4. Use `text-align: center;` in `section figure` to set the content to center.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: azure;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.title1,
.title2,
.title3 {
  padding: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  float: right;
}

.title1 {
  background-color: rgb(223, 209, 25);
}

.title2 {
  background-color: rgb(132, 214, 24);
}

.title3 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

section p {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0;
}

section figure {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col_lg_4 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 31.33%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color: #909090;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 994px) {
  .col_md_6 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color: #909090;
  }
  .col_md_12 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color: #909090;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col_sm_12 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color: #909090;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MENU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mod2_sol/css/sytles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_6 col_sm_12">
      <header class="title1">PIZZAS</header>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
        <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
      </p>
      <figure>
        <img src="pizza.jpg" alt="pizza">
        <figcaption>Try our latest Supreme Pizza</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_6 col_sm_12">
      <header class="title2">BURGERS</header>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
        <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
      </p>
      <figure>
        <img src="burger.jpg" alt="burger">
        <figcaption>Try our latest Supreme Burger</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="col_lg_4 col_md_12 col_sm_12">
      <header class="title3">BEVERAGES</header>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br> Error cupiditate ipsa sint iusto a voluptas quas quis,
        <br> ex nisi fugit placeat eius possimus impedit sed distinctio minus recusandae. Fugiat, modi.
      </p>
      <figure>
        <img src="beverages.jpg" alt="beverages">
        <figcaption>Try our Latest Chillers</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there no way to achieve this with positioning?

Comment: In this specific situation the floating around the header is only possible with `float` rule. Positioning `absolute` inside of `relative` is a good tool, but not for this case.

Comment: Hey just one thing even after using width and height attribute in css for the images if I give an incorrect path no space is being left for the img. Is that feature also outdated?

Comment: For spaces you should put strict size in pixels, but it will be a problem to guess the size of each image, as long as some issues with adaptivity. I would not recommend to do this. This is a very rare situation, when the image path is incorrect, try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all `position: absolute` removes the element out of the document flow, that means the space that the element take will be `removed`, so that's why other elements will move a little up.

So a way of setting the `titles` on the top right side and still take the space.

I will set the following for the `parent element` (section):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

And for the `titles` remove the `position` and `top / left` properties and add the following:

```
margin-left: auto;
```

When you set the `margin-*direction*: auto` it will move the element to the oposite direction.

`Css flex module` is a great way of creating layouts. Try learn it and it will make thing easier. [source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I will look up the flex module for sure but right now the course I'm pursuing has only taught positioning and floating and this an assignment from the course, so there must be a way to achieve the same with relative/abs positioning. Could you help me with that?

Comment: So more exactly you want the titles to be on the right side and still take the space ?

Comment: Yes , exactly nothing should be on the same line as the titles

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use CSS flex module or bootstrap 4, you can achieve this easily.
In the current code you should use `px` instead of `%` and column top padding should be similar of button height.